# Empty result list on django-filter page startup

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm using https://github.com/alex/django-filter

When user opens the page with filter at the first time, they see the empty form and full list of results.

I need to not to display the result until user press Search for a first time.

In other words - django-filter should not display any results if parameters **list** (in url) is empty, and display all results if parameter **values** (in url) is empty.

[image: screenshot]

Source

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters

from product.models import Product

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [ 'shortname', 'fullname', 'description', 'product_type' ]
```

**views.py**

```
from product.filters import ProductFilter

def product_search_in_ancestors(request, product_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)    
    p = get_object_or_404( Product, pk=product_id )

    q = Product.objects.filter( id__in = p.GetChilds() )

    filter = ProductFilter(request.GET , queryset=q )

    return render_to_response( 'product/product_search_in_ancestors.html',
        {'product':p,
        'filter': filter
         },
         context)
```

[Link to same issue on github](https://github.com/alex/django-filter/issues/237)

Comment: The problem is, the default view of a Filter is to return ALL the results. You may need to edit your view. Can you post it?

Comment: I've post my very simple code

Comment: I was going to say that you could prevent the display of results if there were no parameters in the url, but I realized this would prevent the display of the form as well. So I'm not sure if what you want is possible unless you create a seperate page for just the form, and another with the form/results.

Comment: In best - I wish to display form and results on single page. This is default behavior of django-filter.

Answer (score 8):

After some studies, I've found this simple solution

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [ 'shortname', 'fullname', 'description', 'product_type',   ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # at sturtup user doen't push Submit button, and QueryDict (in data) is empty
        if self.data == {}:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.none()
```

I think, this solution is stable. How do you think?

Comment: When I try your solution my filter form does not render.

Comment: Post some more details, please

Comment: Yes, when I place this in my init the records do not show up, but neither does the filter.form containing my filters. If I manually add parameters to the get querystring the form renders but as default it is just not rendering in the template. I am using crispy forms, if that makes a difference.

Comment: May be my solution does not aplly to crispy, I do not test them