# Display all record on django-filter page startup

Tags: django, django-filter

I have the inverse problem of [Empty result list on django-filter page startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211058/empty-result-list-on-django-filter-page-startup).
I would like that on startup my view display all records before user can apply filter.

I don't have (found in the reply of my linked question) :

> The problem is, the default view of a Filter is to return ALL the results.

This is my view :

```
class EntrepriseList(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = EntrepriseTable
    model = Entreprise
    template_name = 'stage/entreprise_list.html'
    filterset_class = EntrepriseFilter
    paginate_by = 30
```

And my filter :

```
class EntrepriseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
   nom = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='nom')
   ville = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='ville')
   class Meta:
       model = Entreprise
       fields = ['nom', 'ville', 'secteur']
```

**ANSWER :**

It turns out it's as easy as setting the strict variable to False in the View class.[source](https://timonweb.com/posts/django-filters-problem-how-to-display-all-results-when-filter-is-not-set/)

Comment: Please add code for your `EnterpriseFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the 2.0 release. A workaround is to set `strict=False`.

https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/930#issuecomment-410177356