# Django-filters FilterView shows empty list on page load

Tags: django, django-filter

So I want to link to a given page that has filters on it, and have it display every item in the table before I click search, and only stop displaying items when bad input is given. My problem is similar to the following problem, with a few differences. [Empty result list on django-filter page startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211058/empty-result-list-on-django-filter-page-startup)

The differences being the poster's default behavior is my desired behaviour and I am using class based views, not functional views.

My urls:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'advising'
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.MyList.as_view(), name='MyList'),

]
```

my views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from django.template import loader
from .models import *
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from .filter import *

class MyList(FilterView):

    template_name = 'advising/MyList.html'
    context_object_name = 'tables'
    filterset_class = MyFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Table.objects.order_by('Name')
```

my filter:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Table

class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Table   #The table this form will reference 
        fields = ["Name"]
```

my template:

```
    <form  method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>

    {% if tables %}
        <ul>
        {% for table in tables %}
            <li>{{table}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>Nothing to see here!.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Is there any way to mimic the behavior of searching for an empty string when the page first loads?

To be very specific, I want the url advising/ to have the same behaviour as the url advising/?Name=

Right now advising/ always gives me an empty list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a post with the same issue I'm having (no idea why it was never coming up on Google) where the issue was solved. It's as simple as adding the line "strict = False" in my view.

This is the question I found that answered it for me:
[Display all record on django-filter page startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130798/display-all-record-on-django-filter-page-startup?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This should be selected as answer.

Comment: @coler-j My bad. When I first tried to select it as answer I got a warning message that it was too soon to select my own comment as the answer, and I haven't been on the site for awhile and it just slipped my mind.