# csv report From filtered Data in django

Tags: django, report, export-to-csv

i have a search field in my django app and filtering Data work well . when i want get csv report , whole of record will be print in csv not filtered data . thank you for help me .

```
    qs=EventkindofProblem.object.all()
    MyFilter=eventfilter(request.GET,queryset=qs)
    return djqscsv.render_to_csv_response(myFilter.qs,append_data_stamp=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Checklist

1. is the filtered result expected to be `all()`? then the filter is working normally. you should use arguments that can filter out the queryset.
2. is the filtered result expected to be `None`? then you will need to override `django-filter>-2.0.0`'s behavior, since django-filter (from `2.0.0`) returns all if form is invalid or the filtered result is null. (how to override django-filter non-strict filtering: [Prevent all data from being displayed with Django-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927028/prevent-all-data-from-being-displayed-with-django-filter/73105049#73105049))

it'd be helpful if you could provide more details about what you're trying to fix.

Comment: my expect is filtered data to be in csv result but all data would be in csv . do you have any sample code foe this ?